# How to find the element for selecting the record in the list box

Tags: angularjs, automation, protractor

I want to select Records from the list box and save the page. Once saved the Selected Records will be populated in the top of the list. Records which are not selected will be displayed below the selected records list.

1. How to identify the Non selected records in the list box to select the record in next update.
2. How to identify Selected Records Data from the list to store in a variable.

Below is the Element for Non Selected Records

```
<li ng-class="{'list-group-item-info': agent.$selected}" ng-repeat="agent in newAgents" style="padding: 5px 15px;" class="list-group-item ng-binding ng-scope" ng-click="toggleSelection(0, 'newAgent')"><span ng-show="agent.$selected" class="label label-success ng-hide"><small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></small></span> Anto</li>

<li ng-class="{'list-group-item-info': agent.$selected}" ng-repeat="agent in newAgents" style="padding: 5px 15px;" class="list-group-item ng-binding ng-scope" ng-click="toggleSelection(1, 'newAgent')"><span ng-show="agent.$selected" class="label label-success ng-hide"><small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></small></span> LokeshMahalingam</li>
```

This is HTML Element for Selected Record

```
<li ng-class="{'list-group-item-danger': agent.$selected}" ng-repeat="agent in agents" style="padding: 5px 15px;" class="list-group-item-success ng-binding ng-scope" ng-click="toggleSelection(0, 'agent')"><span ng-show="agent.$selected" class="label label-danger ng-hide"><small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></small></span>Christopher</li>
```

Code is what i am using now. (This code only selects the first record whether it is selected already or not)

```
this.SkillAgent = element(by.css('li[ng-repeat="agent in newAgents"]'));
```

I also tried the below code but not working

```
this.SkillAgent = element(by.css('li[ng-click="toggleSelection(0, newAgent)"]'));
```

Comment: Need more info about technical things.

Comment: yea i was editing the post. Is that enough for u to check. r do u need more information.

Comment: I was able to find answer for 1 question.I used the below code to handle it.

element.all(by.repeater("agent in newAgents")).get(2); 

by giving the value in get i can select record. Please help me to find answer for 2 question.

Comment: From the selected Record Value "Christopher" needs to be stored in a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to select the value in the list box via get function. 1,2... are row of data's in the list box.

```
this.SkillAgent1 = element.all(by.repeater("agent in newAgents")).get(1);
this.SkillAgent2 = element.all(by.repeater("agent in newAgents")).get(2);
```

Comment: You can get the individual elements from the array via get, yes. But, you were actually asking about identifying the selected elements: `How to identify Selected Records Data from the list to store in a variable.`.

Comment: sorry alecxe i didnt mean ur answer was wrong. i just made my comment for users to select the agents in the list box via get funtion. yeah true i asked u abt data to be stored in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is a relevant `by.repeater()` locator:

```
this.SkillAgent = element.all(by.repeater("agent in newAgents"));
```

To identify the selected elements, we may use [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) function with [`evaluate()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.evaluate) to evaluate the value of `agent.$selected`:

```
this.selectedAgents = this.SkillAgent.filter(function (agent) {
    return agent.evaluate("agent.$selected").then(function (isSelected) {
        return isSelected;
    });
}):
```

Or, alternatively, check the presence of `list-group-item-danger` class:

```
this.selectedAgents = $$("li.list-group-item-danger");
```

Comment: I have updated the code which u have updated can u tel me where i have made a mistake. This is causing an error (Failed: undefined is not a function)
this.SkillAgent3 = element(by.css('li[ng-repeat="agent in newAgents"]'));

var selectedAgents = SGP.SkillAgent3.filter(function (agent)
  {
    return agent.evaluate("agent.$selected").then(function (isSelected) {
        return isSelected;
    });
 });
console.log(selectedAgents);

Comment: @Lokeshsince I don't know on which line the error occurred exactly, are you sure about that `SGP.SkillAgent3` - should not it be `this.SkillAgent3`?..anyway, please provide a complete traceback.

Comment: no actually i have used page object model to use SkillAgent3. i dint change anything. this is wat it is object i used as SkillAgent3
this.SkillAgent3 = element(by.css('.col-sm-3'));

Comment: @Lokesh sorry, difficult to debug without knowing how are you trying to apply the provided solution..

Comment: @Lokesh note that `this.SkillAgent` in my example is the result of `element.all()` call finding the repeater elements.

Comment: yea i can understand. okay let me try with ur code. without my updation and let u know